# Can Jira/Greenhopper do sub-projects?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

Can Jira/Greenhopper do sub-projects?  I want to have two main projects, A and B, and then sub-projects A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2, B3.  This is critical for maintaining order.  I'd like all of the operations teams to be under one operations project, all of the mobile teams to be under one mobile team project, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can create components of the projects in Jira. Components are sub-sections of a project. They are used to group issues within a project into smaller parts.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Defining+a+Component

Comment: Can a component have its own backlog?

Comment: By glory of having a list of issues that have a specific component identified, that can be your "backlog."  There are ways to fanangle your way with Rapid Boards (with ranking and quick filters) to allow you to manage backlogs of multiple projects down to specific components.